# QML ComboBox item DropDownMenu style

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml

I want to use the `ComboBox` type in my project. Is it possible to change the appearance of the drop-down menu (color, shape, text style) or do I need to use a combination of rectangles, `ListView`s and other types?

The following code applies customizations but no modification is defined for the drop-down menu which remains gray:

```
ComboBox {
    currentIndex: 2
    activeFocusOnPress: true
    style: ComboBoxStyle {
        id: comboBox
        background: Rectangle {
            id: rectCategory
            radius: 5
            border.width: 2
            color: "#fff"

            Image {
                source: "pics/corner.png"
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.bottomMargin: 5
                anchors.rightMargin: 5
            }
        }
        label: Text {
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pointSize: 15
            font.family: "Courier"
            font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
            color: "black"
            text: control.currentText
        }
    }

    model: ListModel {
        id: cbItems
        ListElement { text: "Banana" }
        ListElement { text: "Apple" }
        ListElement { text: "Coconut" }
    }
    width: 200
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The current public APIs does not allow customization of the drop-down menu as stated [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/33188). `Qt 5.4`, i.e. `Styles 1.3`, just introduced some properties to customize fonts and text (docs [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-comboboxstyle.html)) but still no public access to drop-down customization.

Also, the example provided in the link does not work with the newer versions of Qt. Here is a modified version I've tested with Qt 5.3, Qt 5.4 and Qt 5.5 (remember to add `import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0` to the imports):

```
ComboBox {
    id: box
    currentIndex: 2
    activeFocusOnPress: true
    style: ComboBoxStyle {
        id: comboBox
        background: Rectangle {
            id: rectCategory
            radius: 5
            border.width: 2
            color: "#fff"
        }
        label: Text {
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pointSize: 15
            font.family: "Courier"
            font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
            color: "black"
            text: control.currentText
        }

        // drop-down customization here
        property Component __dropDownStyle: MenuStyle {
            __maxPopupHeight: 600
            __menuItemType: "comboboxitem"

            frame: Rectangle {              // background
                color: "#fff"
                border.width: 2
                radius: 5
            }

            itemDelegate.label:             // an item text
                Text {
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pointSize: 15
                font.family: "Courier"
                font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
                color: styleData.selected ? "white" : "black"
                text: styleData.text
            }

            itemDelegate.background: Rectangle {  // selection of an item
                radius: 2
                color: styleData.selected ? "darkGray" : "transparent"
            }

            __scrollerStyle: ScrollViewStyle { }
        }

        property Component __popupStyle: Style {
            property int __maxPopupHeight: 400
            property int submenuOverlap: 0

            property Component frame: Rectangle {
                width: (parent ? parent.contentWidth : 0)
                height: (parent ? parent.contentHeight : 0) + 2
                border.color: "black"
                property real maxHeight: 500
                property int margin: 1
            }

            property Component menuItemPanel: Text {
                text: "NOT IMPLEMENTED"
                color: "red"
                font {
                    pixelSize: 14
                    bold: true
                }
            }

            property Component __scrollerStyle: null
        }
    }

    model: ListModel {
        id: cbItems
        ListElement { text: "Banana" }
        ListElement { text: "Apple" }
        ListElement { text: "Coconut" }
    }
    width: 200
}
```

Here `__dropDownStyle` is assigned with a [`MenuStyle`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-menustyle.html) type. Some properties of such type are customized to obtain the desired style, in particular `itemDelegate` (which defines the appearance of an item inside the combobox) and `frame` (overall background). Refer to the linked `MenuStyle` APIs for more details. Overall result:

[image]

Note that this approach *does perfectly work* on Windows and Android whereas on OSX the code is *completely ignored*. One can check the qml style file inside the Qt installation (search for a subpath like `qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop`) to see what changes w.r.t. Windows and try to adapt the provided solution. This part is left up to the reader.

Comment: I've just tested this code on Mac OS X 10.9 and wondered that it's not working for me. Could you suggest me some OS X related edits to make this worked. Nevertheless, on Windows platform everything is fine.

Comment: Well, I tried the code only on Windows/Android at the time, sorry. :)  

You can check the qml style file inside the Qt installation (search for a subpath like `qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop`) to see what changes w.r.t. Windows and try to adapt the solution. 

On my side I'll test the code on my Mac to provide an edit addressing this specific issue (obviously as I have free time).

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks alot! I solved this by next code:

```
Item {
id: app
width: 200
height: 150

ListModel{
    id: dataModel
    ListElement{ name: "Day" }
    ListElement{ name: "Week" }
    ListElement{ name: "Month" }
    ListElement{ name: "Year" }
}

Button {
    id: comboButton
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height / 5
    checkable: true

    style: ButtonStyle {
       background: Rectangle {
           color: control.pressed ? "#888" : "#fff"
           smooth: true
           radius: 5
           border.width: 2

           Image {
               source: "pics/corner.png"
               anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
               anchors.right: parent.right
               anchors.bottomMargin: 5
               anchors.rightMargin: 5
           }
       }
       label: Text {
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.family: "Courier"
            font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
            font.pointSize: 15
            color: "black"
            text: "Day"
        }
    }
    onVisibleChanged: {
        if(!visible)
            checked = false
    }
}

TableView {
    id: tableView
    height: 120
    width: parent.width
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    highlightOnFocus: true
    headerVisible: false
    visible: comboButton.checked ? true : false

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "name"
    }
    model: dataModel

    itemDelegate: Item {
        Rectangle {
            color: styleData.selected  ? "#888" : "#fff"
            height: comboButton.height - 0.5
            border.width: 0.5
            width: parent.width

            Text {
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.family: "Courier"
                font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
                font.pointSize: 15
                color: "black"
                elide: styleData.elideMode
                text: styleData.value
            }
        }
    }

    rowDelegate: Item {
        height: comboButton.height - 0.5
    }

    onClicked: {
       comboButton.checked = false
       tableView.selection.clear()
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the much better answer. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

With current Qt (as of 2020), ComboBox can be customized out-of-the box by specifying `background`, `contentItem`, `indicator` and `delegate`:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox

Answer (score 0):

I've been using approaches like that, but they have a lot of limitations with `focus` management and `z-index` management.

I've end up with the implementation of `ComboBox` which consists of 2 parts: a header which you actually put somewhere and a dropdown component which you create dynamically. The latter consists of an `Item` covering everything (and intercepting mouse activity) and a dropdown which is carefully positioned below the header.

Code is pretty massive to included here so you can see details [in my blogpost with all the code](http://code.jamming.com.ua/ultimate-combobox-in-qml/)