# Combobox styling in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make good looking combobox. To make it I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089779/qml-combobox-item-dropdownmenu-style) as a background.  Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0

ComboBox
{
    id: box
    currentIndex: 2
    activeFocusOnPress: true
    style: ComboBoxStyle {
    id: comboBox
    background: Rectangle {
        id: rectCategory
        color: "transparent"
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "white"
        radius: 15
    }
    label: Text {
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pointSize: 15
        font.family: "Courier"
        font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
        color: "white"
        text: control.currentText
    }

    // drop-down customization here
    property Component __dropDownStyle: MenuStyle {
        __maxPopupHeight: 600
        __menuItemType: "comboboxitem"

        frame: Rectangle {              // background
            color: "green"
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "white"
            radius: 15
        }
        padding.top: 12
        padding.bottom: 12

        itemDelegate.label:             // an item text
            Text
            {
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pointSize: 15
                font.family: "Courier"
                font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps
                color: "white"
                text: styleData.text
            }

        itemDelegate.background: Rectangle {  // selection of an item
            radius: 5
            color: styleData.selected ? "#1fcecb" : "transparent"
        }

        __scrollerStyle: ScrollViewStyle { }
    }

    property Component __popupStyle: Style {
        property int __maxPopupHeight: 400
        property int submenuOverlap: 100

        property Component menuItemPanel: Text {
            text: "NOT IMPLEMENTED"
            color: "red"
            font {
                pixelSize: 14
                bold: true
            }
        }

        property Component __scrollerStyle: null
        }
    }

    model: ListModel {
        id: cbItems
        ListElement { text: "Banana" }
        ListElement { text: "Apple" }
        ListElement { text: "Coconut" }
    }
    width: 200
}
```

Here is the result [image]

Now I have several questions:

- How to remove white corners? I want all corners to be round.
- How to remove shadow under big rectangle? Bottom and Right.
- Is there any possibility to make a gap between dropdown menu and upper rectangle with text?

Comment: Is there a need to use the QtQuick.Controls 1.x rather than 2.0.
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/10/qt-quick-controls-2-0-a-new-beginning/
It's just, that maybe it would be better to concentrate on the new/better technology from the beginning, rather than first making everything perfect with the obsolete, and than throwing it away again... If there is a need for 1.x - alright.

Comment: Above all, 1) customizing new `ComboBox` [is quite easier than the previous control](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox) and 2) in the custom you are using private API which is always bad, even in the case of a "dead" module like quick controls.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo my project is working on qt 5.6. Is there any way to use 2nd version of controls in qt 5.6 or should I move to 5.7? I just have no time to move and if there is any way to solve my problem using 1st version of controls that would be great!

Comment: Ok, it depends on your requirements. New controls can be used in 5.6 as "Lab controls", see the [`ComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qml-qt-labs-controls-combobox.html). This version is not the final one but I've found it quite polished from bugs. If you don't have specific constaints, I would go with 5.7 but mind that 1) support for Android < 4.1 is dropped, 2) support for iOS < 7 is dropped, 3) support for platforms with compilers not fully supporting C++11 is dropped (please refer to [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.7).

Comment: As for solving the issue, well, at the time of the original answer I did spent some minutes trying to figure out the problem. You can check the original styling [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Base/ComboBoxStyle.qml). I've started from there to write my other answer. I'd say, the time spent trying to solve this issue is over the time necessary to port the project. My two cents.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo can I use both 1st and 2nd controls versions in one project?

Comment: Yes, API are incompatible BUT they can be mixed. You can even use controls with the same name thanks to [named imports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37727398/2538363). Again, I don't know the size of your project and the but porting from 5.6 to 5.7 should be a matter of minutes whereas controls 1.x -> controls 2, resolve in few hours (the time needed to move `style` elements inside the controls themselves). As a quicker solution you can use both controls but consider the switch in the near future.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo thank you so much. Project is very big but I will try to fing time to move to 5.7