# ComboBox from QtQuick Controls 1 doesn't recognize flick

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qtquickcontrols, qt5.6

I customized ComboBox from QtQuick.Controls 1 using the following:
[QML ComboBox item DropDownMenu style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089779/qml-combobox-item-dropdownmenu-style)

The only problem I have now is that menu area (that drops down and shows delegates) does not seem to recognize flick gesture (though mouse wheel works).

That's essential for my project because the target is device with touch screen. Scrollbar works, but most of users prefer to flick,  cause scrollbar width is much smaller.

Are there any ways to set the control properties or style to make it recognize flicks?

Qt version is Qt 5.6.3, QtQuick.Controls version is 1.4.

Comment: can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: (1) ScrollBar width can be changed to be finger-friendly, (2) QtQuick.Controls 1.4 have limited life, why aren't you using QtQuick 2?